# Invariant Violation error when running react-native-device-info when trying to get iphone model of device running app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native project and I want to get the iPhone model of the device running the react native application. Based on the model I want to make changes to the react native css because some iphones have notches and some have the dynamic island as well as no notch. All of those things change the overall css. I found a package called `react-native-device-info`. I am trying to integrate it and I tried 5 different ways of integrating it but I keep getting the same error every single time. I tried installing different packages but nothing worked.

Here is the error:

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist. 

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

Here is my App.js file:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(DeviceInfo.getModel())
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I just want to get the device info or have a way to change the css based on wheather the iphone running the react native application has the dynamic island, old notch, or no notch as well as screen size in general.